# Lebesgue points for vector valued functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $Q$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^M$.  Consider $ f \in L^1(Q;X)$, where $X$ is a Banach space. How does one show that the set of all Lebesgue points in $Q$ is of full measure?
My idea was to use density of continuous functions but I'm not sure if continuous functions are dense in $L^1$ for any arbitrary open set $Q$ and Banach space $X$. Are continuous functions dense in the space $L^1(Q;X)$

Comment: Knowing that continuous functions are dense in $L^{1}$ will not help you in showing that almost all points are Lebesgue points. (In the definition of Lebesgue point you can only approximate the numerator, but the denominator goes to $0$ so you cannot draw any conclusion ).

Comment: If $X'$ is separable and $f\in L^\infty(Q)$, it is at least not hard to verify that the set of *weak* Lebesgue points of $f$ has full measure. Have you tried to carry over the proof for $X=\Bbb C$ to the general case?

Comment: The french wikipedia provides a proof using density of continuous functions. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_diff%C3%A9rentiation_de_Lebesgue#Démonstration @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @amsmath - I am trying to carry over the proof for $X = \mathbb{C}$ to the general case, but in order to do that, I need density of continuous functions in the space - and I don't know if density of continuous functions in $L^1$ holds in the general case.

Comment: The answer to your question is given in Theorem 2.16 of https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.020/abschlussarbeiten/MA_Marcel_Kreuter.pdf